# Firestore: filter map without passing field key

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I store game `scores` as a `map` for all `users`:

```
  users (colllection)
    |    
  user1 (document)
    |    
scores: {game1: 2,     
         game2: 6,
         game3: 4,
         game4: 1}
```

I want to delete entries in `scores` for a given `user`, where the score is lower than 3. But I don't want to pass any key (like `game1`) - I want the query to look just at the values (like `2`).

I know I can do it by getting the document and perform updates, but for some reasons (e.g. looots of games) I don't want to get all scores from the database.

Can I do it without getting whole `scores` map? Something like:

```
# do not copy this code, it doesn't work
collection('users').document('user1').where("scores.value", "<", 3).update({"scores.*": firestore.DELETE_FIELD})
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your `scores` field is a map. There is no way to search across multiple fields in a single query with Firestore.

The only solution I can quickly think of is to add an extra array field with just the score values and then query on that with [array-contains-any](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array-contains-any).

So:

```
scores_values: [2,6,4,1]
```

And then:

```
collection('users').document('user1').where("scores_values", "array-contains-any", [1,2,3])
```

---

You won't be able to call `update` on this (or any) query though, as Firestore does't support so-called update queries where you send a write instruction and condition to the database. Instead you'll need to execute to query to get the resulting documents, loop through them, and then update each of them in turn.